# Python : Is there a way to make a script run as admin without prompting after it ran as admin before?

Tags: python, windows, admin, privileges, virus

I'm trying to make a python virus for fun on my computer that runs as admin and copies itself to the startup directory.I have some functions in it that require admin privileges , Let's say I ran it as admin the first time before copying ... is there a code that can give that file some special features to run as admin without asking for prompt ?

Comment: What do you mean sir ? I said it's just for fun and it's not fine as it keeps on asking for privileges

Comment: This is a legitimate, supported use-case for a one-time elevation check at the time of installation or first execution. Any service running as SYSTEM, such as Task Scheduler (hint), can create a process with an administrator's elevated token.